# How can I get a highcharts chart into a Coldfusion document (pdf)

Tags: javascript, svg, coldfusion, highcharts

I'm trying to get a highcharts exported SVG into a Coldfusion .

So far I have:

- Exported the SVG as text from highcharts
- Put the text into a hidden field in a form
- Submitted the form to a further Coldfusion page
- Dumped the form value into the page

  This works well and displays the SVG as an image but only when the 'page' isn't being rendered as a cfdocument. As soon as I add the  tags around the HTML the image disappears and is replaced by a portion of the file in text.

Selected code:

Highcharts -> SVG -> form field

```
var resultsChart = $('#chart_container').highcharts();
chartSvg = resultsChart.getSVG();
$('#chartSvg').val( chartSvg );
```

Form field -> HTML

```
#FORM.chartSvg#
```

When wrapped in

```
<cfdocument pagetype="a4" format="pdf" margintop="1" marginbottom="1" marginleft="1" marginright="1" unit="cm">
```

Doesn't work but is fine in plain .cfm page rendered in the browser.

There may be multiple things wrong here so any help is good !

Comment: I'm guessing the #form.chartsvg# is svg markup? can you share an example? but if it is cfdocument won't render svg

Comment: Chris - I think I realised that on the walk to work this morning. <cfdocument> has a limited sub-set of HTML it will render (div, table, etc.) but SVG isn't amoungst that sub-set :(

Comment: Think of cfdocument as IE6 when it renders HTML.

Comment: Does cfdocument support canvas? Or it's really like IE6? You can try to render Highcharts as canvas using canVG plugin (see bottom of [that docs page](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview)).